# How to get all detail data click Google Analytics GA4 using api in php?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In my case im using spatie/laravel-analytics laravel 10, this my code

```
$data = Analytics::get(
            period: Period::days($day),
            metrics: ['eventCount'],
            dimensions: ['eventName','date'],
            // orderBy: [OrderBy::metric('screenPageViews', true)],
            maxResults: 100,
            // offset: 0,
            dimensionFilter:  new FilterExpression([
                'filter' => new Filter([
                    'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                        'match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
                        'value' => '/'. $pagepath,
                    ]),
                ]),
            ]),
        );
        return response(['data' => $data]);
```

This the response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "eventName": "page_view",
            "date": "2023-10-10T02:49:42.000000Z",
            "eventCount": "10"
        },
        {
            "eventName": "user_engagement",
            "date": "2023-10-10T02:49:42.000000Z",
            "eventCount": "7"
        },
}
```

My expect is

List event Click detail
example

date :
eventName : 2023-10-10T02:49:42.000000Z
eventCount : 10
detailClick : element or url or somethings else
....